# How to define a variable as a Method?

Tags: c#

An Example:

```
class SpecialButton
{
   public SpecialButton(ButtonConfig conf, Method definedMethod)
   {
       button = new Button();
       button.Location = conf.Location;
       //etc.
       button.Click += new System.EventHandler(definedMethod);
   }
}
```

is it possible to define a variable as method? I want to use the delegate for this click event, which comes from outside of this class.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use either `Action<Object, EventArgs>` or just `EventHandler`.

Comment: Do you mean something like this:  public SpecialButton(ButtonConfig conf, EventHandler eventHandler)

Comment: @Vural Acar: note that you won't need to create a new one: `button.Click += eventHandler;`

Answer (score 1):

ok,read articles about delegates [Delegates Tutorial on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)  and [Introduction to Delegates and Events](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/lesson14.aspx)